# Laravel - Image Upload - POST request return Error 405, but method and route exist

Tags: ajax, laravel-8

I'm new on Laravel development and started to build a small application for uploading images via form and drag and drop.

For some reason, when I try to upload an image using the POST route and the Controller's `store` method, the app only returns **ERROR 405 - Method Not Allowed**. I don't know why it's happening.

`web.php`

```
Route::resource('colaboradores', ColaboradoresController::class, ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

My dropzone:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('administrativo.secoes.colaboradores.store') }}" id="image-upload-form">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="image-input" class="dropzone-input" onchange="get_images(this)" multiple hidden>
    <div class="drop-zone" id="image-dropzone" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);" ondrop="dropHandler(event);">
        <div class="inner-elements">
            <label for="image-input">
                <h3>Drag your pictures here</h3>
                <span class="note needsclick">Or click here to manually select them.</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript file with HTTP request through AJAX:

```
function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    document.getElementById("image-dropzone").style.border = "3px solid #00f752";
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(ev) {

    document.getElementById("image-dropzone").style.border = "3px dashed #0087f7";
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        \[...ev.dataTransfer.items\].forEach((item, i) =\> {
            
            if (item.type.includes("image")) {
                const file = item.getAsFile();
                upload_image(file);
            }

        });
    }
}

function get_images() {

    var total_images = document.getElementById("image-input").files.length;

    if (total_images \> 0) {

        for (var index = 0; index \< total_imagens; index++) {

            var file = document.getElementById("image-input").files\[index\];
            upload_image(file);
        }
    }
}

function upload_image(file) {

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", file);
    form_data.append("test", "test");

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta\[name='csrf-token'\]").attr("content")
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: \`${window.location.pathname}/store/\`,
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

}
```

`SobreController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Administrativo;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\SectionCollaborators;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ColaboradoresController extends Controller
{

 public function index()
    {
      //
    }

    public function create()
    {
      //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        try {
            $novo_nome = self::upload_imagem($request);
            return response()->json(["imagem" => "$novo_nome", "mensagem" => "Imagem salva com sucesso."] 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(["mensagem" => "Ocorreu um erro ao salvar a imagem. Tente novamente.", 500]);
        }
        
    }

    private function upload_imagem(Request $request)
    {

    
        if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {

            $request->validate([
                'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,webm,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $img = $request->file;
            $novo_nome = Storage::disk('local')->put('public/img/colaboradores/cards', $img, 'public');

            return basename($novo_nome);
        }
        
    }


    public function update(Request $request)
    {
       //
    }

    private function update_text($object, $nome, $valor)
    {
       //
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
       //
    }

    public function setId(int $value)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        //
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: first check if that route is correct: `route('administrativo.secoes.colaboradores.store')`, see if this route appears by running the command `php artisan route:list`, for last try to use these headers: `$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');` and `$request->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');`, you can create a middleware to add these two